# A yacc shift/reduce conflict on an unambiguous grammar

Tags: grammar, yacc, bnf, shift-reduce-conflict

A piece of code of my gramamar its driveing me crazy.

I have to write a grammar that allow write functions with multiple inputs

e.g.

```
function
  begin
    a:
       <statments>
    b:
       <statements>
  end
```

---

The problem with that its that is statements that are assignments like this

ID = Expresion.

in the following quote you can see the output produced by yacc.

```
  0  $accept : InstanciasFuncion $end

  1  InstanciasFuncion : InstanciasFuncion InstanciaFuncion
  2                    | InstanciaFuncion

  3  InstanciaFuncion : PuntoEntrada Sentencias

  4  PuntoEntrada : ID ':'

  5  Sentencias : Sentencias Sentencia
  6             | Sentencia

  7  Sentencia : ID '=' ID

State 0

    0 $accept: . InstanciasFuncion $end

    ID  shift, and go to state 1

    InstanciasFuncion  go to state 2
    InstanciaFuncion   go to state 3
    PuntoEntrada       go to state 4

State 1

    4 PuntoEntrada: ID . ':'

    ':'  shift, and go to state 5

State 2

    0 $accept: InstanciasFuncion . $end
    1 InstanciasFuncion: InstanciasFuncion . InstanciaFuncion

    $end  shift, and go to state 6
    ID    shift, and go to state 1

    InstanciaFuncion  go to state 7
    PuntoEntrada      go to state 4

State 3

    2 InstanciasFuncion: InstanciaFuncion .

    $default  reduce using rule 2 (InstanciasFuncion)

State 4

    3 InstanciaFuncion: PuntoEntrada . Sentencias

    ID  shift, and go to state 8

    Sentencias  go to state 9
    Sentencia   go to state 10

State 5

    4 PuntoEntrada: ID ':' .

    $default  reduce using rule 4 (PuntoEntrada)

State 6

    0 $accept: InstanciasFuncion $end .

    $default  accept

State 7

    1 InstanciasFuncion: InstanciasFuncion InstanciaFuncion .

    $default  reduce using rule 1 (InstanciasFuncion)

State 8

    7 Sentencia: ID . '=' ID

    '='  shift, and go to state 11

State 9

    3 InstanciaFuncion: PuntoEntrada Sentencias .
    5 Sentencias: Sentencias . Sentencia

    ID  shift, and go to state 8

    ID        [reduce using rule 3 (InstanciaFuncion)]
    $default  reduce using rule 3 (InstanciaFuncion)

    Sentencia  go to state 12

State 10

    6 Sentencias: Sentencia .

    $default  reduce using rule 6 (Sentencias)

State 11

    7 Sentencia: ID '=' . ID

    ID  shift, and go to state 13

State 12

    5 Sentencias: Sentencias Sentencia .

    $default  reduce using rule 5 (Sentencias)

State 13

    7 Sentencia: ID '=' ID .

    $default  reduce using rule 7 (Sentencia)
```

Maybe somebody can help me to disambiguate this grammar

Answer (score 3):

Bison provides you with at least a hint. In State 9, which is really the only relevant part of the output other than the grammar itself, we see:

```
State 9

    3 InstanciaFuncion: PuntoEntrada Sentencias .
    5 Sentencias: Sentencias . Sentencia

    ID  shift, and go to state 8

    ID        [reduce using rule 3 (InstanciaFuncion)]
    $default  reduce using rule 3 (InstanciaFuncion)

    Sentencia  go to state 12
```

There's a shift/reduce conflict with `ID`, in the context in which the possibilities are:

1. Complete the parse of an `InstanciaFuncion` (reduce)
2. Continue the parse of a `Sentencias` (shift)

In both of those contexts, an `ID` is possible. It's easy to construct an example. Consider these two instancias:

```
f : a = b c = d ...
f : a = b c : d = ...
```

We've finished with the `b` and `c` is the lookahead, so we can't see the symbol which follows the c. Now, have we finished parsing the funcion `f`? Or should we try for a longer list of sentencias? No se sabe. (Nobody knows.)

Yes, your grammar is unambiguous, so it doesn't need to be disambiguated. It's not LR(1), though: you cannot tell what to do by only looking at the next *one* symbol. However, it is LR(2), and there is a proof than any LR(2) grammar has a corresponding LR(1) grammar. (For any value of 2 :) ). But, unfortunately, actually doing the transformation is not always very pretty. It can be done mechanically, but the resulting grammar can be hard to read. (See Notes below for references.)

In your case, it's pretty easy to find an equivalent grammar, but the parse tree will need to be adjusted. Here's one example:

```
InstanciasFuncion : PuntoEntrada 
                  | InstanciasFuncion PuntoEntrada
                  | InstanciasFuncion Sentencia

PuntoEntrada: ID ':' Sentencia

Sentencia : ID '=' ID
```

It's a curious fact that this precise shift/reduce conflict is a feature of the grammar of bison itself, since bison accepts grammars as written above (i.e. without semi-colons). Posix insists that `yacc` do so, and bison tries to emulate `yacc`. Bison itself solves this problem in the scanner, not in the grammar: it's scanner recognizes "ID :" as a single token (even if separated with arbitrary whitespace). That might also be your best bet.

---

There is an excellent description of the proof than any LR(k) grammar can be covered by an LR(1) grammar, including the construction technique and a brief description of how to recover the original parse tree, in Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen, Parsing Theory, Vol. II (Springer Verlag, 1990) ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540517324)). This two-volume set is a great reference for theoreticians, and has a lot of valuable practical information, but its heavy reading and its also a serious investment. If you have a university library handy, there should be a copy of it available. The algorithm presented is due to MD Mickunas, and was published in 1976 in [JACM 23:17-30](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321924) (paywalled), which you should also be able to find in a good university library. Failing that, I found a very abbreviated description in [Richard Marion Schell's thesis](http://archive.org/details/methodforconstru904sche).

Personally, I wouldn't bother with all that, though. Either use a GLR parser, or use the same trick bison uses for the same purpose. Or use the simple grammar in the answer above and fiddle with the AST afterwards; it's not really difficult.

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis.  Any hints on where to find the proof that there's an LR(1) grammar equivalent to an LR(2) grammar?  Any hints on how to modify this grammar so that the problem is avoided (which might be just a special case of the general solution)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yours for the chewing.

Comment: Chomp; chomp; ... thanks. I'll have to go and dig out my (antique) Dragon Book; it's a good few miles away at the moment. (And I can't give you a second +1, sorry!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your answer help me to solve the shift reduce conflict but in the next instance of my proyect, this solution can produce problems. This is becase now I need construct a intermediate code using reverse Polish notation. So I need store the instances functions like this: a: b=3 -> [a, b, 3, =, :]. With the example that you expose here I can not recognise when finish the instance so I don't know where to store the ':' token. Can you bearings me with that?